# Max formula and blank

Tags: formula

Can Max formula handle fields with blank values?

I have three number fields field a, field b, field c with default value as blank(default custom field setting)

Max(field a, field b, field c) is causing an internal salesforce error if I fill out field a and field c and try to save the record without field b. Strangely I can save the record by just filling out one of the three fields.

Is this because of blank field b and max cannot handle max(blank,value,value), if so has this been documented somewhere?

[image]

Update: sorry that I did not clarify, I am using the fields as part of a formula in a workflow rule, so treating it a blank/ zero is not an option

Comment: Did you raise a ticket with support yet? Did you check the option to treat null values as zero?

Comment: Did you use "treat blanks as blanks"? I'd expect it to error; try using "treat blanks as zeroes" instead.

Comment: I am using the max value in a field update

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yep raised the ticket

Answer (score 2):

Use [BLANKVALUE](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#BLANKVALUE) function for each field:  `MAX( BLANKVALUE(Field1__c, 0), BLANKVALUE(Field2__c, 0), BLANKVALUE(Field3__c, 0) )`

Comment: Thats exactly what i am doing now but my question is along the lines of if salesforce handles it internally , if not is there a doc that connwcts the blankvalue and max function

Comment: I doubt the error is related to the MAX function itself - does it work well when you have values on all 3 fields used in the calculation?

Comment: yes the goes away and the record saves fine if I go ahead and fill out all three fields the error goes away. I do have recalculate workflow on other workflows as soon as this field update is complete. I do not think the workflow updates are messing up anything

Answer (score 0):

Using blank values or if null is only useful if using positive numbers, If I assume null to be 0 and all my other values are negative I'll end up with 0 when it should have been the largest negative value. This is clearly a bug that needs to be fixed on the salesforce side. @Rao what happened with your ticket?